# Explanation of Taylor's Theorem as used in Bredon's proof of Proposition IV.7.2 in Topology and Geometry

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

The proof in question is about a differentiable function $f: \mathbf S^n \to \mathbf S^n$ with regular value $p$ whose preimage has exactly one point. Bredon assumes without loss of generality that $f(p) = p$ and the differential of $f$ at $p$ is the identity. He then says, "By Taylor's Theorem, we can write $f(x) = x + g(x)$ in some local coordinates $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ about $p$, **where, for some $\epsilon > 0$, $\lVert g(x)\rVert < \frac{1}{2} \lVert f(x)\rVert$ for $0 < \lVert x\rVert \leq 2 \epsilon$.**" I'm struggling to match the bolded part of this statement to any of the statements of Taylor's Theorem I'm familiar with. I would expect something like $\lVert g(x)\rVert < \frac{1}{2} \lVert x\rVert$ for $0 < \lVert x\rVert \leq 2 \epsilon$ (just from differentiablity of $f$), or $\lVert g(x)\rVert \leq  \frac{1}{2} \lVert d^2f_{\xi(x)}(x, x)\rVert$, where $\xi(x)$ is some point on the segment between $0$ and $x$. Could someone explain why we can assume the bound on $g$ given by Bredon?

Comment: I see how to prove this only if $f$ is assumed to be $C^1$. No such bound holds if one assumes only that $f$ is differentiable at $p$.

Comment: I have a feeling that the author meant "smooth" rather than "differentiable", so I would be fine assuming that.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I see how to get a bound like $\|g\| \le c\|df - I\|$. You just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the function $\phi(t) = f(tx)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume $f$ is $C^1$. If $\|df_x-I\|\le\frac13$ for $\|x\|<2\epsilon$, then  by the mean value theorem for all such $x$ we have $\|f(x)-x\|\le \frac13\|x\|$, and so $\|f(x)\|\ge \frac23\|x\|$. It follows that $\|g(x)\| = \|f(x)-x\|\le \frac13\|x\|\le \frac12\|f(x)\|$. (You can modify this, if necessary, to get strict inequality.)